# No symbols loaded in gdb with breakpad core file

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, google-breakpad

I am already using google-crashdumper but I want to try breakpad now. I have integrated google-breakpad in my project and I'm deliberately crashing the application to test the breakpad.

I am converting the minidump to core file and loading in the gdb as follows

```
gdb application --core=corefile.core
```

And the problem is there are no symbols from the shared library. It looks something like the following:

```
Thread 2 (LWP 16357):
#0  0xf7789bd9 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000a48 in CountAUXV (pvdso_ehdr=<optimized out>, pnum_auxv=<optimized out>)
#2  CreateElfCore (handle=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xf70befac>, 
    writer=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xf70befa8>, 
    is_done=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xf70bef74>, prpsinfo=0x80, user=0xf769b9eb, prstatus=0x0, 
    num_threads=1314, pids=0x0, i386_regs=0x0, fpregs=0x0, fpxregs=0x8e763f8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_>, pagesize=175652892, 
    prioritize_max_length=175652896, main_pid=-150208408, 
    extra_notes=0x8494476 <boost::asio::detail::posix_event::wait<boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex> >(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&)+134>, extra_notes_count=175652440) at src/elfcore.c:770
#3  0x00000a48 in CountAUXV (pvdso_ehdr=<optimized out>, pnum_auxv=<optimized out>)
#4  CreateElfCore (handle=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xf70befb0>, 
    writer=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xf70befac>, 
    is_done=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xf70bef78>, prpsinfo=0xf769b9eb, user=0x0, 
    prstatus=0x522 <CryptoPP::PSSR_MEM_Base::RecoverMessageFromRepresentative(CryptoPP::HashTransformation&, std::pair<unsigned char const*, unsigned int>, bool, unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) const+600>, num_threads=0, pids=0x0, i386_regs=0x0, 
    fpregs=0x8e763f8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_>, fpxregs=0xa78401c, pagesize=175652896, prioritize_max_length=4144758888, 
    main_pid=139019382, extra_notes=0xa783e58, extra_notes_count=175652416) at src/elfcore.c:770
#5  0x00000080 in ?? ()
#6  0xf769b9eb in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (LWP 16350):
#0  0xf7789bd9 in ?? ()
#1  0xff8d29b8 in ?? ()
#2  0xf74f0527 in ?? ()
```

Just posting 2 threads. It is similar with every thread which is quite weird as I have provided my executable also to the gdb.

Then I compared the breakpad's core-file with crashdumper's core-file. In crashdumper core-file everything is being loaded perfectly. All the sysmbols from all the library. It is showing the thread program where the crash took place. But nothing as such in breakpad version.

What am I missing with breakpad?? I googled a lot but in vain. Didn't find anything and anyone facing such problem.

***UPDATE***
I might be knowing why it is behaving like that. I checked `info sharedlibrary` in gdb and found out following:

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary 
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/D05FAC9D-0A87-6A47-5B5F-4ACE88DA8B2B-linux-gate.solinux-gate.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/07158AB3-A302-F4D9-E226-2E743AAD5F62-libarmmem.solibarmmem.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/0CF3E746-A497-4FC2-344C-5150C99DA98F-libdbus-1.so.3.8.13libdbus-1.so.3.8.13
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/86022950-B6CD-75CC-5231-9E660744CC01-librt-2.19.solibrt-2.19.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/D43EAF3E-9294-46AB-EBEC-7D2843FAD327-libdl-2.19.solibdl-2.19.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/083C9754-79F6-5740-5007-420864280D28-libm-2.19.solibm-2.19.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/73F07B39-C2C2-F2E1-976B-28C79E9C7380-libpthread-2.19.solibpthread-2.19.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/8E621420-AFA9-0E78-0FC6-66408F455863-libc-2.19.solibc-2.19.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/2848F9C5-0705-5011-7118-B3528CB1B127-ld-2.19.sold-2.19.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/98309410-5F29-2228-E94C-CE5597E94B8E-libnss_compat-2.19.solibnss_compat-2.19.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/ADB0DF4C-35D2-97E7-D08B-08CCC5D05BAE-libnsl-2.19.solibnsl-2.19.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/7A15AA2B-CFE8-EAE9-ED53-5AE09F11D847-libnss_nis-2.19.solibnss_nis-2.19.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/0B47D611-FAE4-DF70-897D-B17FC2403E6B-libnss_files-2.19.solibnss_files-2.19.so
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/44B0344D-3E34-451F-180E-80F7260552C9-libX11.so.6.3.0libX11.so.6.3.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/6980DABF-E4A3-BA5A-77BD-A926F982F7DA-libxcb.so.1.1.0libxcb.so.1.1.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/761E80BE-9902-2C81-CE65-EB25C918F928-libXau.so.6.0.0libXau.so.6.0.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/E82DCDA7-DBC9-E32F-4910-42EB91EE45E1-libXdmcp.so.6.0.0libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/61020107-52E1-1B5E-F21D-C4B038AB639A-libXext.so.6.4.0libXext.so.6.4.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/129CD9AD-EAC2-ACF7-CB4A-1676EAE9A2C5-libXrandr.so.2.2.0libXrandr.so.2.2.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/A9E8A41A-1DA0-1FDD-A54D-0B1C5D35E90F-libXrender.so.1.3.0libXrender.so.1.3.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/DC369B36-7E04-CEC6-4D5B-3FDF02CB5A94-libXtst.so.6.1.0libXtst.so.6.1.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/F0A290AE-076C-3270-25B8-52C134D70034-libXi.so.6.1.0libXi.so.6.1.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/A77F22F7-692A-A25D-BA51-9F725850878B-libXdamage.so.1.1.0libXdamage.so.1.1.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/4C202434-CFCB-ABB5-A350-73E99C5D9E2F-libXfixes.so.3.1.0libXfixes.so.3.1.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/E35954A9-31A1-A86D-6CEE-9A4532E31D10-libSM.so.6.0.1libSM.so.6.0.1
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/2254A820-8A49-A402-DC7B-7BCC21EF2BC3-libICE.so.6.3.0libICE.so.6.3.0
                        No          /var/lib/breakpad/129A60DD-4279-492F-67BB-BD62B86BE6B3-libuuid.so.1.3.0libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

So it is looking for the shared library where it does not exists if I am not wrong. Even after I installed breakpad there was no such folder `/varlib/breakpad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

https://breakpad.appspot.com/1214002

This patch was already applied but did not mentioned anywhere. For anyone who face such problem.

But still there is one problem with this. User can only provide one path and the libraries has been loaded from multiple paths. I don't know if this is already been implemented!!!